# Load one column of csv into javascript variable

Tags: jquery, csv, d3.js

I have a CSV file formatted as String1, String2, Int1, Int2.  I would like to put each row on a scatterplot using D3 with the ints as the axes.  So I figured out how to load the CSV data using D3 into a table, but then I realized, why not just load the CSV columns directly into variables?

So, does anyone know how to load a single column of a CSV at a time using D3 or jQuery?  Or even better, is there a better solution that I should be considering?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6453094/parse-and-access-remote-csv-with-javascript-only might help

Comment: d3 shoudl give you the csv as a collection of row objects. So the simplest thing to split out columns would be to use map or the convenient _.pluck from [underscore.js](http://underscorejs.org/)

Answer (score 0):

First off, thanks to Andrew Davis over at thecodingtutorials.blogspot.com for his immensely helpful walkthroughs of using D3 and especially loading CSV files using D3.

D3 tutorial: http://www.thecodingtutorials.blogspot.com/2012/07/introduction-to-d3.html

Loading CSV: http://thecodingtutorials.blogspot.com/2012/07/using-csv-and-text-files-with-d3.html

Multi-column CSV: http://thecodingtutorials.blogspot.com/2012/08/using-multi-column-data-with-d3-part-1.html

Anyway, the short answer is that the CSV columns can be treated like properties within the object.

Where before I had

```
var vis = d3.select("#tryHere").append("svg:svg").attr("width", w).attr("height", h);
vis.selectall("circle")
   .data(data).enter().append("svg:circle")
   .attr("cx", function(d) { return x(d.x) })
   .attr("cy", function(d) { return y(d.y) })
   ....
```

I need to encase the plotting code in

```
 d3.csv("MyFile.csv", function(rawData) {
```

and replace the last two lines with:

```
 .attr("cx", function(d) {return x(d["XColumnName"] )}
 .attr("cy", function(d) {return y(d["YColumnName"] )}
 ....
```